Как достать куки из ответа на запрос?
Пытаюсь решить проблему которую сам себе и создал в целях обучения.
Я хочу аутентифицироваться(залогиниться) с фронта отправив POST запрос в body {login, password}. В ответ я получаю в Cookie какое-то value (в примере ниже это userId), на фронте хочу взять из Cookie это значение сохранить его в localStorage, чтобы бы при обновлении страницы оставаться залогиненным - если есть кука в localStorage отправлять запрос на сервер проверяя не устарела ли она и отправлять последующие запросы в ручную добавляя в header эту куку
Но я никак не могу Cookie вручную, хотя в devTools они видны и даже в ответе сервера в headers есть Set-Cookie (через document.cookie, тоже не получается). Что я делаю не так или возможно логика с сохранением в localStorage неправильная?
Функция для запросов
export async function fetchAPI(url = '', data, method = 'POST') {
    const options = {
        method: method,
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        },
        credentials: 'include',
    }

    if(data) {
        options['body'] = JSON.stringify(data)
    }

    const response = await fetch(url, options);
    return response;
}

Запрос на аутентификацию
async (data) => {
    try {
        const response = await fetch('http://localhost:3000/login', data, 'POST');

        console.log(response.headers.getSetCookie()); // выводит []
        console.log(response.headers.get('Set-Cookie')); // выводит null
        if(!response) {
            throw new Error()
        }

    } catch (e) {
        console.error(e);
    }

Server.js
import express from 'express';
import cookieParser from 'cookie-parser';
import cors from 'cors';

const app = express();
app.use(cookieParser());

// Подключаем middleware для CORS
app.use(cors({
    origin: 'http://localhost:5173', // Указываем домен вашего фронтенда
    credentials: true // Разрешаем передачу куки
}));

// Обработчик POST запроса для аутентификации и установки Cookie
app.post('/login', (req, res) => {
    // В реальном приложении здесь будет происходить аутентификация пользователя

    // Устанавливаем Cookie
    res.cookie('userId', '123456789', { maxAge: 900000, httpOnly: true });

    // Отправляем ответ
    res.send('Login successful. Cookie set.');
});

// Пример защищенного ресурса, который требует наличие Cookie
app.get('/protected/resource', (req, res) => {
    // Проверяем наличие Cookie
    const userId = req.cookies.userId;

    if (userId) {
        res.json({ message: 'Protected resource accessed successfully.' });
    } else {
        // Если Cookie отсутствует, возвращаем ошибку
        res.status(401).json({ error: 'Unauthorized. User not logged in.' });
    }
});

// Запуск сервера на порту 3000
app.listen(3000, () => {
    console.log('Fake API server running on port 3000');
});


Во-первых, "кука в localStorage" звучит как чушь, а во-вторых, вы ж сами запретили доступ к куке, прописав httpOnly

В-третьих, к заголовку Set-Cookie нельзя получить доступ из JS в браузере. Никак. Вообще никак. Да и не нужно. Смысл кук в том что их сам браузер когда и если это можно и нужно.

Никак не достать.
Спецификация явно запрещает любой доступ к заголовкам Set-Cookie из JS.
Вы можете получить значение куки из document.cookie при условии что кука поставилась на домен текущей страницы и не имела флаг httpOnly.

А каким образом мне сделать так, чтоб при обновлении страницы я был по прежнему залогинен и смог отправлять разные get запросы? Ведь кука сбросится

@YourDeveloper с чего бы? Куки не удаляются при обновлении страницы.

@YourDeveloper куки не удаляются при обновлении страницы и могут автоматически посылаться браузером при каждом запросе, если указано, что в запрос нужно включать credentials (но в случаях, если для них идет один домен/поддомен и проставлены флаги) MDN Http-Куки.
Также учитывайте, что ручное проставление кук в хэдере запросов может быть запрещено браузером (например Google Chrome это запрещает), поэтому нужно действовать именно через credentials (и вполне возможно, что на сервере нужно разрешать их принимать) :)

@EfimPushkarev не «может быть запрещено», а точно запрещено https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#forbidden-request-header

@AlexeyTen видел эту ссылку, но подумал что может быть для XHR какой-нибудь такой стандарт не прописан :) Сути в общем-то и не меняет) Не стоит руками пытаться посылать и все)
