как записать значение из Cookies ответа в переменные?
Знаю как записать в переменные значение параметра ответа. А как можно записать значение из Cookies ответа?

Возможно ответ тут - https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1585148/Как-достать-куки-из-ответа-на-запрос
